# Self join in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, self-join

I am trying to build a self join in Laravel. I wish to compare 2 columns in the same table.

When I write this in my controller:

```
$char_name_obj = User::find($user->id)->characters()->where('lord_id', '=', 'id')->get();
```

lord_id is one column, id is the other column in the same table named characters. This returns nothing. I am sure I need to do a self join to be able to achieve this.

Character model:

```
class Character extends Eloquent {

    protected $table = 'characters';

    protected $fillable = array('lord_id','char_name', 'char_dynasty', 'picture');

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('User');
    }

    public function Titles()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('Title');
    }

    public function LordCharID()
    {
        return $this->has_one('Character');
    }
}
```

I don't know how to use the last function `LordCharID()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

has_one is the Laravel 3 function; so if you're using Laravel 4, you need to use [hasOne](http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#relationships)

You can use whereRaw to compare columns:

```
User::find($user->id)->characters()->whereRaw('lord_id = id')->get();
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't find that in the Documentation, but maybe I can miss something.

Comment: @SerbanSpirescu to be clear, whereRaw is in the documentation http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#basic-usage, but it's used to execute ANY raw where statement on a table, not just column comparison.